# Change Tabbar background color in override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, tintcolor

I need to load tabbar items. Here i need different background colors for tabbar in different tabs . i am changing bar tint color in  didSelectItem. But it's background color is not changing . while loading tab bar it is working fine .

Here is my code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

         if(tabIndex == 1){
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ALBUM_BG_COLOR
            self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ALBUM_BG_COLOR

        }else if(tabIndex == 2){
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ME_BG_COLOR
            self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ME_BG_COLOR

        }
    }
```

While loading tabbar tint color is loading fine

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        if(item.tag == 1){
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ALBUM_BG_COLOR
            self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ALBUM_BG_COLOR

        }else if(item.tag == 2){
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ME_BG_COLOR
            self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ME_BG_COLOR

        }
    }
```

While changing tabbar items it's not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Solution , making Completely transparent UITabBar in app delegate

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

And changing background color on didSelectItem

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    println(" selected index \(item.tag)")

    if(item.tag == 0){
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    if(item.tag == 1){
        self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ALBUM_BG_COLOR

    }else if(item.tag == 2){
        self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ME_BG_COLOR

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.TAB_BAR_ME_BG_COLOR` to `tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()`. Hope this help.